# Java Map variable --> parse the Key to an Object

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I am reading a json string to 'Map' variable.

This is the json :

```
   "RootKey [name=Gil, department=]": {
        "active": true,
        "isPresent": true
    }
```

This is the variable :

```
private Map<String,Properties> map;
```

The key is String :  "RootKey [name=Gil, department=]"
The value is saved as an Object 'Properties'
while 'Properties' is a class which have 2 variables :

```
public class Properties {
   private String active;   
   private String isPresent;
}
```

The question is how to parse the 'key' so I will be able to get the name and the department separately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some regexp once you retreived the key (as it's a String):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*? \[name=(.*?), department=(.*?)\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourKey);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // contains the name
    System.out.println(m.group(2)); // contains the departement
}
```

If you never heard of regex (which I doubt) or don't understand my regexp, try this online regexp tester: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

If your key format is always the same, you can use a dumb parser of the String inside the key. a sample would look like this: ( feel free to improve by adding at least some error validation \ error handling )

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String test = "RootKey [name=Gil, department=]";
    KeyInfo cls = getKey(test);
    System.out.println(cls.name + " " + cls.department);
}

private static KeyInfo getKey(String jsonKey) {
    // parse the content between brackets
    String[] tokens = jsonKey.substring(jsonKey.indexOf('[')+1, jsonKey.indexOf(']')).split(", ");
    // build your key info
    return new KeyInfo(tokens[0].substring(tokens[0].indexOf('=') + 1),
            tokens[1].substring(tokens[1].indexOf('=') + 1));
}

private static class KeyInfo {
    private final String name;
    private final String department;

    private KeyInfo(String name, String department) {
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
    }
}
```